# Why does True == True evaluate to True, when {a statement that's equal to True} == True evaluates to false?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm having trouble explaining the contents of this script in Python3:

```
x = "hello"
y = "ll"
x in y == True # evaluates to False
y in x == True # evaluates to False
y in x # evaluates to True
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use parentheses:

```
(y in x) == True # evaluates to True
```

[image]

All comparison operators have the same precendence and are therefore evaluated left-to-right.

Chained comparisons in  python have the property that:

```
a OP1 b OP2 c
```

([6.10 Comparisons](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons))

is the same as

```
a OP1 b and b OP2 c
```

meaning that

```
y in x == True
```

evaluates to

```
y in x and x == True
```

which becomes

```
True and False
```

which is `False`.

I believe comparison chaining was originally introduced to allow expressions like `a < b < c` to have the more conventional mathematical meaning, though with `==` and `in`, it is arguably less meaningful.

Comment: What you say is true, but according to §6.16 of https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html, it should not be the case. Or am I misreading it? According to this chapter, "==" and "in" have the same precedence and in this case, "Operators in the same box group left to right"